# How to create record in route53 hostedZone

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I have created CloudFront distribution and trying to attach that record to the route53 hosted zone.
when I'm trying it is giving below error.

> An error occurred: myDNSRecord - Invalid request: Expected exactly one
> of [AliasTarget, all of [TTL, and ResourceRecords], or
> TrafficPolicyInstanceId], but found none in Change with
> [Action=CREATE, Name=abc.yz.com., Type=A,
> SetIdentifier=null] (Service: AmazonRoute53; Status Code: 400; Error
> Code: InvalidInput; Request ID: 81fd7f48-3ffb-4fa1-b1ba-cef599834a07;
> Proxy: null)

```
myDNSRecord:
      Type: AWS::Route53::RecordSetGroup
      DependsOn:
        - cloudFrontDist
      Properties:
        HostedZoneId: !Ref 53HostedZoneId
        RecordSets:
          - Name: abc.yz.com
            Type: A
            TTL: 300
            AliasTarget:
              HostedZoneId: Z2FDTNDATAQYW2
              DNSName:
                Fn::GetAtt: [cloudFrontDist, DomainName]
```

I want to host the CloudFront distribution URL in route53

Comment: can you put your full cloud-formation source for reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alias records **don't use TTL**. So remove it from your template:

```
myDNSRecord:
      Type: AWS::Route53::RecordSetGroup
      DependsOn:
        - cloudFrontDist
      Properties:
        HostedZoneId: !Ref 53HostedZoneId
        RecordSets:
          - Name: abc.yz.com
            Type: A
            AliasTarget:
              HostedZoneId: Z2FDTNDATAQYW2
              DNSName:
                Fn::GetAtt: [cloudFrontDist, DomainName]
```

Comment: @Karthik No problem. Glad it worked out:-)